# Ubuntu Kickstart/seed file - weak password

Tags: password, preseed, kickstart

I have used the kickstart generator tool to generate a kickstart/preseed file for ubuntu KVM installations which has worked well until now. It stopped working when I switched over to using a very weak password, which results it halting on an additional option shown below:

[image]

What do I need to add to the kickstart file in order to confirm that this is ok?

```
# Initial user
user ubuntu --fullname "" --password ubuntu
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add the following line to the kickstart file:

`preseed user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true`

It appears that one can just replace `d-i` with `preseed` in order to get the normal preseed instructions to work such as [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt).

Full credit to @Hamy and @Jeremy which this answer is fully derived from. I just wanted to put an "idiots guide" answer for people like myself.

Answer (score 3):

An Ubuntu Preseed file

```
# The installer will warn about weak passwords. If you are sure you know
# what you're doing and want to override it, uncomment this.
d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true
```

You need to expressly answer that installer question.  The last line is what you need.  The source documentation is here: [Link to Ubuntu Preseed documentation and examples](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/preseed-contents.html)

Comment: Thanks but I tried that and it didnt work for me as you can see in this kickstart script: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ddLQtuHz

Comment: @Programster Kickstart is a RedHat thing that Ubuntu partially supports, whereas Preseed is a Debian thing that is the "proper" way to automate a Ubuntu installation. Many setups only need the limited ks feature set, but for odd cases like yours, you want to use a Preseed command. Jeremy is telling you to either a) add a separate preseed config file, or b) use the "preseed" command that ubuntu recognizes in ks files to put some ps in your ks. You tried (2) but forgot to use preseed. See https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/ia64/automatic-install.html

Comment: @Hamy are you saying I just need to change `d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true` to `preseed d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true`? Ill try this later thanks

Comment: Yup, I believe that's what you need! I'm working on a similar problem now, I'll try to follow up if I determine that this method works :-)

Comment: Hm, looks like the proper syntax is actually `preseed user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true` - omit the d-i